# In SharePoint how to display custom ribbon button to particular lists only?

Tags: sharepoint, list, button, custom-controls, ribbon

I am having four external list "List1", "List2", "List3", "List4". I have added a custom ribbon button Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="ATEAgWorkOrderButton"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="600"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
         Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
          <Button
           Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.ATEAgWorkOrderButton"
           Alt="Click on this button to Add"
           Sequence="3"
           Image32by32="/_layouts/Images/Project/image.png"
           Command="ATEAg_WorkOrder"
           LabelText="Add Detail"
           TemplateAlias="o2"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
         Command="ATEAg_WorkOrder"
         CommandAction="javascript:alert("Hello Success");" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

The button is now visible in all the external lists. But I want to make it visible for only "List1" and "List2". How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explore the Andrew Connell's Ribbon Customization Deep Dive.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2011/04/16/sharepoint-2010-ribbon-customization-deep-dive.aspx

He goes into how to solve these problems.  In short instead of binding a customization for all lists of a certain type, you can register a javascript function that gets called to determine if you button should be shown or hidden.  In this function you can determine which list is currently active.

Answer (score 0):

If all your lists are associated with a ContentType, you can set the registration id of the custom action to the ContentType id.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx):

> RegistrationID: Optional Text. Specifies the identifier of the list or
>   item content type that this action is associated with, or the file
>   type or programmatic identifier (ProgID).